# error in statement: no such column, but column exists

Tags: sql, rsqlite

I'm using RSQLite to combine two tables.
I check every single step, but still didn't figure out what went wrong. 
Here is my script:

```
ol5_H3K4me1_mesc_common<-dbGetQuery(con,"select* from H3K4me1_mesc where H3K4me1_mesc.V2=H3K4me1_mesc_common.V2 and H3K4me1_mesc.V3=H3K4me1_mesc_common.V3")
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  error in statement: no such column: H3K4me1_mesc_common.V2
> dbListFields(con,"H3K4me1_mesc_common")
[1] "V1" "V2" "V3"
```

Comment: `H3K4me1_mesc_common` is not in the `from` so its columns are irrelevant to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your posted query table `H3K4me1_mesc_common` is not part of `FROM` clause and so is the error. You wanted your query to look like below where `t1` and `t2` are table alias for respective tables

```
select t1.* from H3K4me1_mesc t1 
join H3K4me1_mesc_common t2
on t1.V2 = t2.V2 
and t1.V3 = t2.V3
```